# What is cross-resistance against lice?

Tags: head-lice, sensitivity-intolerance

I have read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touching_heads) on Wikipedia the following passage:

> Head lice infestations might serve as a protection against body lice
>   by inducing cross-resistance.

I understand that cross-resistance for different kind of poisons or drugs, but what is cross-resistance against lice?

Answer (score 2):

They're saying that a head lice infestation might provoke the immune system into more effectively resisting body lice infestations.

Comment: Thank you, sorry i just don't understand how body may resist such an infestations. I mean if it is some sickness when body may have antibodies, but in case of lices, how this works?

Comment: @Yola That would make a good question.